# Remove header YAML with sed from a markdown file

Tags: bash, sed, pandoc

I have a text in markdown that I want to pass to HTML with pandoc and delete the header. This is the command:
`sed '/---/,/---/d' java.md | pandoc - -f markdown -t html5 --wrap=none -o java.html`

and this is the header:

```
---
title: Instalar JAVA en Ubuntu
subtitle: Subtitle
author:
    - I am an author
date: \today{}
---
```

The problem is that it also removes part of the text where this `------` appears.

What code do I need from `sed`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to only remove the first occurrence?

Comment: yes, I want to eliminate the first occurrence

Comment: you can also do `pandoc -t markdown`... without the `-s` option, it won't emit the yaml metadata...

Comment: This also works, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) to prevent `-------` from being matched.

```
sed '/^---$/,/^---$/d' file.md
```